# Add the files of python3_apscheduler_3.10.4.bb on Yocto

Tags: yocto, pypi, apscheduler

I would like to ask if there is any information about python3-APScheduler_3.10.4.bb. I searched all over the Internet and there is no information about it. I tried to write it myself, but it is not feasible at all on Yocto.

Bitbake recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "In-process task scheduler with Cron-like capabilities"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler"
AUTHOR = "Alex Grönholm <apscheduler@nextday.fi>"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=f0e423eea5c91e7aa21bdb70184b3e53"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/34/5dcb368cf89f93132d9a31bd3747962a9dc874480e54333b0c09fa7d56ac/APScheduler-3.10.4.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "cf4dd44a52f05e4a06dc104de52e41f5"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "e6df071b27d9be898e486bc7940a7be50b4af2e9da7c08f0744a96d4bd4cef4a"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python3-six python3-pytz python3-tzlocal"

inherit setuptools3
```

Image install line in image:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "python3_apscheduler"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python packages that exist on PYPI there is an easier solution, you can check out this great [article](https://hub.mender.io/t/how-to-work-with-python-applications-and-modules-in-yocto-project/1135) in mender authored by 'mirzak'.

In his example it looked at the end like this:

```
SUMMARY = "This is a python module for monitoring memory consumption of a \
process as well as line-by-line analysis of memory consumption for python programs"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/conda-forge/memory_profiler-feedstock"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=cde4ca348bb7feea790673481be0d980"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "5fe93d5035288095c4f86ef69ee19f37"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "4e5b73d7864a1d1292fb76a03e82a3e78ef934d06828a698d9dada76da2067b0"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "memory_profiler"

inherit pypi setuptools3

RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
    python3-psutil \
"
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, it is not used in the recipe

> inherit pypi setuptools3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).